TeamViewer on CentOS 8 Only Listening on 127.0.0.1:5939 and Not Accessible Remotely
Problem:
I'm running TeamViewer on a CentOS 8 server that's located in a different network. I’ve successfully installed TeamViewer, and the service seems to be running fine, but I can’t access it remotely using the TeamViewer ID. When I check the ports, I see that TeamViewer is only listening on 127.0.0.1:5939, which means it’s only accessible locally and not over the network.
Here’s the relevant output:
$ sudo netstat -tulnp | grep teamviewer
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5939          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3952/teamviewerd

I’ve confirmed that the firewall is configured to allow traffic on the necessary ports:
$ sudo firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens3
  sources:
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 5901/tcp 5938/tcp
  protocols:
  forward: no
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

Question:
How can I configure TeamViewer on CentOS 8 to listen on all network interfaces (0.0.0.0:5939) so that it is accessible remotely? Is there something I'm missing in the configuration, or does TeamViewer have limitations in this environment that I'm not aware of?
Additional Info:
OS: CentOS 8
TeamViewer Version: [Specify version if known]
Using Traefik as a proxy
Background:
I'm not an OS expert and primarily have experience in writing code, so any detailed guidance or explanations would be greatly appreciated!
